# When I assign a bigger number to a long long variable, why the variable is 0?

Tags: c++, long-long

`unsigned long long mem_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024 *1024;`

Why in vs2013, I find the variable `mem_size` is not 2<sup>40</sup> but `0`?

Comment: Are you using 64bit os?

Comment: The variable is unsigned so if you reach the limit, it goes on overflow and returns to the minimum value 0.

Comment: `1024` has type `int` and won't be promoted to `long long` automatically. Use `1024ULL`.

Comment: @Evg Please turn that into an answer. It seems even already sufficiently explained.

Comment: @Sintuz `1024*1024*1024*1024` is `2^40` can be represented with 64 bits. No going over the top there. Even if it overflows and wraps around it shouldn't be 0.

Comment: @Yunnosch, there should be a perfect dupe for this question. I'm looking for it now.

Comment: @Evg worth mentioning then int overflow is undefined behavior, any value could be expected than 0 as well?

Comment: @Evg Fine with me. Either name it or provoke another user in providing it by making an answer. Please. I want this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Yunnosch, perfect dupe has been found. :)

Comment: @Evg I wish voting the quality of a found dupe were possible.... There are so many examples of abused hammers now. And of course I do not mean this one.

Comment: This is my first question in stack overflow. Thanks all , especially @Evg。Your answer is ok for me。@Evg

Comment: What you do with the result of an expression does not affect how the expression is evaluated. Your expectation that assigning it to a `long long` would cause the computation be done as a `long long` is not met.

Comment: So I should hide this question ,right ? @Evg

Comment: @Johnson, please don't do it. It's a useful question. Question with a dupe ≠ bad question that should be deleted.

Comment: @SpongeBob `int` is 32-bit in both 32 and 64-bit platforms, so the result is the same: the expression overflows